# Editing multiple words on the same line at the same time with textmate

Tags: textmate

I know about using alt/option and the 'Edit each line in selection' tools in Textmate to edit multiple lines at the same time. What I'm wondering now is if there's a way to edit multiple words in a selection or single line. Here's an example

`a, b, c -> self.a, self.b, self.c`

Select `a, b, c`, magic command, type `self.` and get `self.a, self.b, self.c`

Even better if this could work on multiple lines

```
a, b, c,     self.a, self.b, self.c,
d, e, f  ->  self.d, self.e, self.f
```

Is there such a thing in Textmate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I created a bundle for you: https://github.com/kizu/EditEachWord.tmbundle

There I created two simple commands which allow you to can insert something before or after all words in a line or a selection.

Actually, it's rather simple to create your own commands that would insert a custom generated snippets with multiple tabstops, so you could do a lot of things with them.

Also, if you'd want to edit multiple parts, you can try my other bundle: https://github.com/kizu/Hayaku.tmbundle with two features: [multiple carets](https://github.com/kizu/Hayaku.tmbundle) and [inline replaces](https://github.com/kizu/Hayaku.tmbundle/wiki/Replaces/).

Enjoy!

Comment: Super nifty! I'll try it out soon! :)